# Заполнение фрагмента данными из Loader

Tags: android, android-fragment, loader

Не могу понять, где лучше вызвать метод для наполнения фрагмента данными из Loader.
В зависимости он запрошенного режима работы приложения к активности прикрепляется фрагмент, который наполняется данными из соответствующего Loader'a. Примерно так:

```
Cursor cursor; //Курсор который инициализируется лоадером
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

someFragment f = new SomeFragment();
if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
f.getData(cursor.getString(0)) //передает данные из курсора во внутренний метод фрагмента, который наполняет его информацией
}
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, f).commit(); //и заполненный фрагмент выводится на экран
```

По скольку лоадер подгружает данные в отдельном потоке, не успеват инициализировать курсор и в строчке cursor.moveToFirst() происходит обращение к null-объекту.

Можно ли как-то приостановить вывод фрагмента до инициализации курсора?
Пытался так же наполнять фрагмент данными из метода onLoadFinished(); и выводить фрагмент от туда же, но смущает заметка в документации:

> Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment
>   transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an
>   activity's state is saved.

Не желательно выводить пустой фрагмент на экран до заполнения его информацией. Может кто-то подсказать, как лучше реализовать логику?
Хотел сделать что-то вроде появляющегося прогрессбара, который отображает прогресс подгрузки данных и замораживает интерфейс приложений (до появления данных и фрагмента собственно и никакого UI нет по этому в этом случае это не критично) но ни как не могу понять, как приостановить работу основного потока в этой точке, определить завершение загрузки и продолжить работу потока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй интерфейсы, когда твой лоадер загрузится, вызывай метод интерфейса, который будет вызывать 
`someFragment f = new SomeFragment();
if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
f.getData(cursor.getString(0)) //передает данные из курсора во внутренний метод фрагмента, который наполняет его информацией
}
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, f).commit(); //и заполненный фрагмент выводится на экран`

и все будет у тебя ок, все как ты хочешь

Comment: А можно немного подробнее. Что за интерфейс и каким образом можно вызвать его метод, если в интерфейсах нет реализации методов. Т. е. его кто-то должен реализовать, какой-то класс. Что-то вообще не пойму каким образом все это практически применить.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузнецов я так понимаю, он говорил про `Callback` [тык](http://www.fandroid.info/urok-13-osnovy-java-metody-obratnogo-vyzova-callback/)

Comment: Да все верно,  это Callback.

Comment: Для примера вот, 1-й ответ смотри 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android